# Why shouldn't we use parenthesis for manipulators that don't take arguments in C++?

Tags: c++

For example `setw` takes an integer argument which means we could write `setw(5)`, whereas the manipulators `left` and `right` don't take any.

1. Why would it be wrong to use `left()` and `right()` instead of `left` and `right`?
2. What is the difference between manipulators which take arguments and ones which don't?

Comment: 1. Why would it be good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would it be wrong to use left() and right() instead of left and right?

Because it wouldn't compile!

It would also add extra function calls for no benefit at all. If `left` was meant to be called as a function then it would have to return something which did the same purpose as `left` does today, which would require an extra type to be defined and extra overloads of `operator<<` to handle that type. Why bother?

> What is the difference between manipulators which take arguments and which don't?

Ones which take arguments are stateful, they return some object that stores the arguments, and then uses those arguments to alter the stream state e.g. for every manipulator taking an argument you have something like this:

```
struct SetW { int w; };

SetW
setw(int w) { return SetW{w}; }

ostream&
operator<<(ostream& out, SetW sw)
{
  out.width(sw.w);
  return out;
}
```

There is a type like `SetW` for each manipulator must be an overload for each of those types.

But for the manipulators with no argument they are defined (roughly) like:

```
ostream&
left(ostream& out)
{
  out.str.setf(ios_base::left, ios_base::adjustfield).
  return out;
}
```

and there is an overload that handles *all* manipulators of that form, by accepting a pointer-to-function as the argument:

```
using zero_arg_manipulator_type = ostream& (*)(ostream&);

ostream&
operator<<(ostream& out, zero_arg_manipulator_type f)
{
  f(out);
  return out;
}
```

This needs no extra types like `SetW`, and only one overload to handle all of the zero-argument manipulators, so is simpler and results in less code.

If you had to call `left()` then it would need to return some custom type like `SetW`, so another type would have to be defined for every manipulator, and there would have to be more overloads. This would complicate the library, make it slower to compile, and might make executables larger and slower.

(The details above are simplified for the sake of this answer, in reality the functions are templates that take `basic_ostream` instead of `ostream`, and some manipulators work with `ios_base` or `basic_ios` not basic_ostream`, but that doesn't change the overall idea of how it works).

Answer (score 2):

It would be wrong, because it would not work :) - standard library is designed like this, and `left()` would just not work.

'No argument manipulators' are just function (you can call them by yourself like `std::left(stream)`) ([see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left))

there is an overloaded `operator<<` that accepts such functions as argument, allowing to write `out << std::left`, which will generate code same as `std::left(out)`. So `out << std::left` is just a convenient notation. That also means you can easily create your own manipulators.

Where it comes to passing some real arguments, a more complicated code is needed, for example (not a real example, just explanation):

```
struct setw_t { int width; };
inline setw_t setw(int n) { return setw_t{n}; }
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, setw_t t)
{
  out.width(t.width);
  return out;
}
```

as a result, calling `setw(5)` will produce more complicated code, but that's not a surprise, as `5` has to be passed somehow.

Allowing to write `std::left()` (for example for consistency) would require to create a lot of such 'tag structures' and would only complicate adding new ones.

Comment: That's a great answer now, with basically the same info as mine but much shorter and clearer!